# Possible to Sign In as a Cognito User Pool user using AWS SDK for PHP version 2?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to write some code in our PHP application that currently uses the AWS SDK for PHP version 2.8.31 to essentially sign in a user that's in a Cognito User Pool so that we can then use that user's identity to call AWS API Lambda methods. The API Gateway will use Cognito as the authorizer.

The problem I'm having is that all the examples I'm finding online for getting this done are using version 3 of the PHP SDK that has the `CognitoIdentityProviderClient` class that provides the `adminInitiateAuth` method that gets the Access Token that you need to call the API Gateway with.

Is there a way to do this with the v2 of the AWS SDK for PHP (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/)?

The `CognitoIdentityClient` seems like it might be the way, but the only relevant methods I see are `getId` and then `getCredentialsForIdentity`, but these still don't get me the Access Token I need to pass to the API Gateway. I can also see `GetOpenIdToken` and `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` but the `'IdentityProviderName'` parameter that they are asking for doesn't seem to support Cognito User Pool as the provider?

I'm just hoping that someone out there knows a enough about these methods to let me know if this is even possible with the V2 of the SDK.

Comment: GetCredentialsForIdentity method will provide you with access key, secret key and session token. You can use these three to authenticate any API calls you make.

Comment: The problem is that to call `getCredentialsForIdentity`, I need to provide an `IdentityId`, which from the looks of it, I can only get by calling `getId`. However, the `getId` function only takes an `accountId` and `identityPoolId`... so it doesn't help me with how to provide the User Pool user's credentials to sign them in.

Comment: `getId` requires `identityPoolId` as well as the `idToken`. After that you pass the `identityId` that you got along with cognito user credentials to `getCredentialsForIdentity`.

Comment: Are we looking at the same API? `getId` takes an `AccountId` and an `IdentityPoolId` (as per [getId API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityClient.html#_getId)), and this also requires the identity pool to be set to allow unauthenticated access. And `getCredentialsForIdentity` takes only the `IdentityId` you get from calling `getId`, no mention of user credentials: [getCredentialsForIdentity API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityClient.html#_getCredentialsForIdentity)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html
Logins parameter is not specified when you are using it for unauthenticated access.

Comment: Right, I don't want to use it for unauthenticated access, I want to use a Cognito User Pool as the Authorizer for an API Gateway we already have. So I need to first login to the User Pool as some user, get the access token for that user, and then pass that access token to the API Gateway so it can authorize with the user pool. And I seem to be stuck on that first step - logging in as a particular User Pool user. It seems really odd that this core functionality doesn't exist in V2 of the PHP SDK.